# Netbeans: C/C++ file-template variables documentation needed

Tags: c++, netbeans, editortemplates, netbeans-7

I'm looking for a faq or overview on C/C++ template-file variables in Netbeans (7.0).
(Not to be confused with the template technique). Those you see under Tools > Templates > C++ templates.

e.g.

```
%<%CLASSNAME%>%  %<%DEFAULT_HEADER_EXT%>%  %<%DATE%>%
```

which are automatically filled when you create a new cpp/header file out of that file-template.

The help for the Java template-variables with Freemarker is very extensive, but I found nothing for the C++ equivalent.

When I did a search on `CLASSNAME DEFAULT_HEADER_EXT`, google gave me 5 results... which were not helpful. So if there is a reference or api, it seems to be hidden somewhere... Not even the netbeans site had any information about that.

And if there is nothing, maybe someone can at least tell me if there is a way to format the `%DATE%` variable (like this in Java's Freemarker format: `${date?date?string("yyyy")}` ).

Still no luck... can't believe that such a feature is not documented... Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: I suspect few if any of the C++ experts here use NetBeans (or Eclipse). OK for Java programming, but for C++? Nah.

Comment: Yea I know it's not "standard", but Visual Studio is just making problems on my system. The C++ support in netbeans is really good (now), except of that template thing. And other editors are not an option for me (personal taste ;-) ).

Comment: Docs don't exist yet.  An issue has been filed https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198793

Comment: @Kirschi: Have you tried QtCreator?

Comment: sorry for the late answer... I wasn't aware until now that you can code in C with QtCreator. But I guess it doesn't matter - I love netbeans. I tried a lot of different IDEs but netbeans is the one and only one ;) I guess I have to live with it or wait until there is Freemarker support.